# How to optimize this function "checkCode" in java

Tags: java, option-type

I have this code which calls the function check valid code in java

```
 do {
        System.out.print("Enter Code: ");
        infor.setCode(sc.nextLine());

        if (check.checkCode(infor.getCode()) == true) {
            boolean aa = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (infor.getCode().equals(list.get(i).getCode())) {
                    aa = false;
                    System.out.println("Code already exists in DB");
                    break;
                }
            }   
            if (aa) {
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Failed!! Try again!");
    } while (true);
```

and I am trying to optimize to this code:

```
boolean aa;
    do {
        aa = true;
        System.out.print("Enter Code: ");
        infor.setCode(sc.nextLine());

        if (check.checkCode(infor.getCode()) == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (infor.getCode().equals(list.get(i).getCode())) {
                    aa = false;
                    System.out.println("Code already exists in DB");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Failed!! Try again!");
    } while (aa == false);
```

but it cannot return the input which does not meet requirement function and not allow me to retype. Any solution to this?

```
public boolean checkCode(String input){
    String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure what the problem is - can you elaborate on "cannot return the input"? I don't see where you're trying to return the input in either the 'before' or 'after' code. Is it an error you're getting, or is the code with the actual problem not shown here?

Comment: my do while loop ask a user to input code if it doesn't meet the requirement of function checkCode, or it already exists in database, user must retype it. I am trying to optimize the first code which worked for me, but when i replace it with the second code it skips the error and keep doing next input

Comment: Is the code you've posted exactly what you're running? I've just tried running it and both examples work exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}$");
private static final Predicate<String> IS_CODE_VALID = code -> PATTERN.matcher(code).matches();

public static String getNewCode(Scanner scan, Set<String> existedCodes) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter Code: ");
        String code = scan.nextLine();

        if (existedCodes.contains(code))
            System.out.println("Code already exists in DB");
        else if (IS_CODE_NOT_VALID.test(code))
            System.out.println("Failed!! Try again!");
        else
            return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be significantly better with some explanation about why you've made the changes you have.